# Is it possible to animate changes to data represented in CorePlot?

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-plot, observer-pattern, key-value-observing

I'm looking to use CorePlot to show a bunch of data from an API, I'd like to observe changes so the graph can change dynamically. For the best experience, I'm thinking that the data should be animated.

I understand that it's entirely up to me to observe changes in my data model, but I'm having trouble figuring out how I can animate a change in the plot itself. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything built in for this yet. You could create a second plot with the new data, add it to the graph, and animate it in. Remove the old plot (with or without animation) when appropriate. The best type of animation to use will probably depend on which plot type you're using.